# Optimizing JOIN with WHERE

Tags: mysql

Lets say I have 2 tables. The first table, table_1, contains each posted content including

```
table_1
   title, 
   author name, 
   email, 
   city_name, etc.
```

The second table provides a lookup for table_1. It has 2 columns,

```
table_2
   city_id and 
   city_name.
```

For instance, city_id =1 corresponds to New York, city_id =2 corresponds to Chicago... and so on. Under the 'city' column in table1, the city_id is listed which can easily be joined with table 2, producing a readable city name.

Would the following statement be as efficient as using a WHERE with city_id? Reason being is that I would be filtering results based on a city which is a string and I don't want (or need?) to correlate each input to its matching ID number in table2.

```
SELECT table1.city, table2.city_name 
FROM table1 
WHERE table2.city_name=(input city name)
JOIN table2.city_name ON table2.city_id = table1.city
```

Comment: Your where clause is in a funny place...

Comment: You've written `city_name` in `table_1` above.  That looks like a mistake given your question.  Do you want to edit the question?  Also, as jswolf19 is hinting, your WHERE and JOIN lines are mixed up.  Please see the MySQL syntax at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Because the join is an *inner join* the following should lead to equivalent execution plans.** (That is, they *should* exhibit the same performance characteristics -- write the SQL clearly and let the SQL engine do the dirty optimization work.)

As presented in the other answers:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.city_name 
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 ON table1.city_id = table2.city_id
WHERE table2.city_name = (city_input);
```

And, as what I believe is the "optimized form" presented in the question:

```
SELECT table1.*, t2.city_name 
FROM table1 
JOIN (SELECT * FROM table2
      WHERE table2.city_name = (city_input)) AS t2
ON table1.city_id = t2.city_id
```

This is because of the [Relation Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) Model that SQL follows; at least under RA the equality ("selection") here can be moved across the join (a "natural join" in RA) while keeping the same semantics. Of course, "to make for certain", run a query analysis. The most basic form is using `EXPLAIN`.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly following what the question is, but I'll say that the proper way to handle a query in which you need to filter on a specific city name, rather than ID, would be like this:

```
 SELECT table1.*, table2.city_name 
 FROM table1 
 JOIN table2 ON table1.city_id = table2.city_id
 WHERE table2.city_name = (city_input);
```